# What is an equation connecting $w$ and $r$ when $r=60$ and $W=4320$ when $w$ and $r$ are directly proportional

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, inverse

So this question is written weight w and Newton’s r is directly proportional to the cube of its radius r cm I thought I would just divide $4320$ by $60$ $= 72$ and the equation would be $w=r·72$, but according to the book it’s wrong and the answer is $w=0.02r^3$ But I don’t know how they got to this answer and help is much appreciated.thank you.

Comment: Is *"$w$ and $r$ are directly proportional"* a direct quote or was the relation given slightly different, like "the growth of ... is directly propotional"? But then you would need an anchor, in your computation you have the implicit assumption that both are also zero at the same time.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann it was exactly written as the weight w and Newton’s r is directly proportional to the cube of its radius r cm

Comment: But that is more information, it already fixes the relation to $w=cr^3$ and it only remains to find $c$. So the question is asking for the weight of some body when it grows proportionally in all directions.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann so how does that work

Comment: It is literally the translation of "the weight is proportional to the cube of the radius". Note that "Newton" is the unit of weight=mass times acceleration.

Comment: I strongly suspect a transcribing error in that sentence. It should have been "the weight $w$ **in Newtons** is directly proportional to the cube of its radius $r$ **in** cm". As has already been mentioned, Newtons are just the unit of weight. "and Newton's r" makes no sense, no matter how you try to parse it, particularly since $r$ is defined later as the radius. Who made the error and when I cannot say, it could have been the original author, or some later copier.

Answer (score 0):

so i assume the question says the weight is  directly proportional to the cube of its radius.

so writing it mathematically,

$w∝r^3$

This mean w is some function of $r_3$, that could look like $w=Ar^3$, where A is some constant. Now you can use the values given,

$4320=A \times 60^3$

making $A=0.02$

TBH if that all the question has given you its not worded very well, if w is proportional $r^3$ that could make the equation a lot of things i.e. $w=Ar^3+B$, where A&B are constants, and many others...